# Wrong Cancellation of Medical Insurance

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, health-insurance, healthcare, medical-bill

I enrolled in medical, dental and vision during open enrollment. I saved the summary after I submitted. The summary shows all my elections. Insurance was supposed to start on September 1st. I received a letter from my employer on September 18th that shows my medical waived-meaning no insurance.

I contacted our HR to fix the error. They said I have to appeal. I appealed and I submitted the summary page that shows all my elections including medical. HR told me it can take up to 90 days to resolve for something that is not my fault. Now, I will be without insurance for up to 90 days and if they approve to reinstate, they will go and make the medical premium deductions retroactively. If I have any medical bill during the 90 days I will not be reimbursed.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: Collecting premiums retroactively means that the insurance coverage should apply retroactively as well. Are you sure that insurance won't cover any claims during the 90 days? Did HR say this or are you assuming? You can always submit the claim after the fact, once insurance is established.

Answer (score 4):

> if they approve to reinstate, they will go and make the medical
> premium deductions retroactively. If I have any medical bill during
> the 90 days I will not be reimbursed.

I hope that is a misunderstanding. If they are going to collect the premiums they will have to pay your expenses.

Check your pay stubs to make sure they didn't take a deduction. I know somebody who ran into this a long time ago. They won the dispute because the company had been pulling the premiums from their paycheck. That meant the issue wasn't the employees fault.

In case they refuse to re-instate you should get coverage. You might have a few options:

- Coverage from the Affordable Care Act, or
- COBRA coverage if you are a new employee, and you had coverage with your old company. There are time limits so you need to act fast.
- Coverage from your spouses employer. There is a time limit for this also, so check into this before time is up.
- Check to see if there are any COVID related exemptions you can use. They can be related to open season or COBRA.